# How to use custom x and y values when ploting ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I am a new user of Mathematica and hope someone can help me.

I have data file which has 1500 columns and 500 rows and would like to plot it using ListDensityPlot function. Everything goes well when I write the PlotRange function and indicate min and max values for the x and y-axis. Unfortunately, I need to use custom range, because in my data first row should correspond to 0, second row to 0.1, 3rd - 0,5, etc. Thus in my ListDensityPlot the x-axis should be the first column of the data and y-axis - the first line of the data. Could you, please, suggest how can I plot this data using ListDensityPlot function.

Comment: Look at the DataRange option for ListDensityPlot.

Comment: Does this example help? `data = Table[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 4, .1}, {y, -10, 10, .1}];
{ListDensityPlot[data], 
 ListDensityPlot[data, DataRange -> {{-10, 10}, {0, 4}}]}`  If not, we will need a minimal example to help.

Comment: Dear Jason, thank you for the response. I am using DataRange, but this function assigns only interval . But I need to use x-values from the first column and the y values from the first row.

Comment: I thought it might be a bit more complicated. Can you come up with a small example either with a small subset of your data or a command to create fake data with a `Table` command? It's still hard for me to visualize what you want to do, but an example might make it easier to understand.

Comment: Supose we have data:
M = {{0.01, 700, 710, 720, 730, 740, 750}, {0.1, 0, 6, 5, 2, 1, 
   0}, {0.5, 0, 2, 5, 5, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 3, 5, 5, 1, 0}, {2, 2, 3, 5, 2,
    1, 0}, {5, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0}, {10, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1}}
the first row should indicate wavelengths and the first column - time.
ListDensityPlot[M, MaxPlotPoints -> {1000, 1000},
 DataRange -> {{700, 750}, {0, 10}},
 PlotRange -> {{700, 750}, {0, 10}}]

If we use ListDensityPlot function and use DataRange - we chose interval, but I need that in y-axis first line would be at 0.01, second on 0.1, third at 0.5, and so on.

Comment: If we did not use PlotRange function, then Mathematica will atributte first row to 1, second row to 2, ect. However I can not find option, which atributes selected collumn and row values to x and y-axes values such as in OriginPro or Excel. Of course they should be there, but I am quite new here and can not find this option :)

Comment: I think I understand, have a look at [this notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/jasonb/Published/Help_for_SE_question_209046.nb).  If you take what you wrote in the comments here and put them into the question (hit the edit button, use the help to format code properly, etc), then I would post that as an answer here.  Without doing that, your question isn't self-contained and may end up getting closed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It looks quite simple now, but unfortunately it is not very straightforward for the beginner :) Thank you again!